# Not able to get a request token using /oauth/initiate in Magento. Error says - oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token

Tags: magento, oauth

I've been trying to authenticate my oAuth consumer to the Magento application for 2 weeks now. I just can't seem to get a break through.

I've configured the REST roles and attributes to make everything accessible. Now the next step is to get a request token.

I've been trying to authenticate using Google Chrome's REST client at the url - `/oauth/initiate`. I've entered all the parameters needed to authenticate the app namely -
consumer key, consumer secret, oauth version, timestamp, nonce, signature method.

But the error I get is this -

```
{
messages: {
error: [1]
0:  {
code: 401
message: "oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token"
}
}
}
```

Which seems very strange to me, cause there are no parameters absent from what I can make out. Someone please help me out. I've been stuck on this badly.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Magento isn't returning the parameter `oauth_token`.
So there is something else wrong with your request. The first time I ran into this, it was because I wasn't providing an `oauth_callback` parameter.